# (API) How do I insert row in more than one table

Tags: sql, asp.net

is it possible to insert row in different tables using POST method? The tables are connected with an autoincrement primary key and a foreign key in the other table. I can insert into the parent table but not the child table as the foreign key has to be specified. Is there a way to add the foreign key value?

Comment: Can you return the new primary key when you insert the row into the parent table, then use that to insert into the secondary table?

Comment: @dvo I am so sorry but I do not really understand. Do you mean that I should use HTTPGet method?

Comment: The web method should be POST since you are adding new data to your tables. Research stored procedures in your choice of dbms where you can INSERT with a return parameter. In your code, you can capture that return and call another INSERT to insert it into the second table. You can get a little more advanced and do both in one stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

if you use EF when you insert a record in parent, when you call savechange() then it return the new key of parent to object then you can use the key to insert to child.
if I understand your question.

```
var parent=new parent(){};
dbcontext.table.add(parent);
dbcontext.savechange();
var child=new child();
child.parentid=parent.parentid;
dbcontext.table2.add(child);
dbcontext.savechage();
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are using sql server, right click on the table an add a insert trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_tblRental_ForInsert 
ON dbo.Rental
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   Insert into second_Table( name) .....
End
```